# Getting multitouch on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, touchegg

if **geistest** returns me the following result, can I not get multitouch gestures on my machine like Mac?

```
Device 9424 added
attr "device name" = "Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer"
attr "device id" = 9424
attr "device touches" = 16
attr "direct touch" = true
attr "independent touch" = false
attr "device X minimum" = 0.000000
attr "device X maximum" = 4095.000000
attr "device X resolution" = 12000.000000
attr "device Y minimum" = 0.000000
attr "device Y maximum" = 4095.000000
attr "device Y resolution" = 21000.000000
Device 11152 added
attr "device name" = "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
attr "device id" = 11152
attr "device touches" = 2
attr "direct touch" = false
attr "independent touch" = false
attr "device X minimum" = 1278.000000
attr "device X maximum" = 5664.000000
attr "device X resolution" = 42000.000000
attr "device Y minimum" = 1172.000000
attr "device Y maximum" = 4682.000000
attr "device Y resolution" = 52000.000000
error subscribing to gestures
error subscribing window 0x000000f3
```

Or is it possible for me to use a software like **Touchegg** to get multitouch?